# Php Byte Array Packet

Tags: c#, php

I have a c# library which practically starts listening on a tcpip server an accepts a buffer of a certain size.

I need to send this packet as Byte array from php over the socket in a form of byte array or equivalent.

The packet is constructed for example byte[1] (a flag) is a number from 0 to 255 and byte[6] to byte[11] contains a float number in a string fromat for example:
005.70 which takes 6 bytes representing every character.

I managed to send the flag but when i try to send the float number it does not convert on the other side (C#).

So my question how can i send a byte array to c# using php?

From the C# part the conversion is being handled as follows:

```
float.Parse(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(Data, 6, 6));
```

Comment: How doesn't the `float.Parse` work? Is there an exception?

Comment: If You put a break point when You get the Data, what is the value of it?

Comment: I have submitted the answer, As it seems if you dont escape the actual value you need the Data is filled with the equivalent ascii value (being the byte value)

Answer (score 0):

Just after i have posted the question i have dictated my answer. I am not 100% sure if this is the right way but it managed to convert correctly.

Here is the answer:

I created an array of characters and escaped the flag (4) to be the actual byte value being (4) but i didn't escape the money value

```
$string = array (0=>"\0", 1=>"\4", 2=>"\0", 3=>"\0", 4=>"\0", 5=>"\0", 6=>"5", 7=>".", 8=>"7", 9=>"\0", 10=>"\0");
```

Imploded all together with nothing as glue:

```
$arrByte =  implode("", $string);
```

and sent over the opened socket:

```
$success = @fwrite($this->socket, $arrByte);
```